# shell script is not getting executed using crontab

Tags: shell, cron

A shell script is not getting executed when using the crontab @reboot option.
I confirmed it by running the below command

```
grep CRON /var/log/syslog
```

output:

```
Aug  4 22:05:57 ubuntu CRON[817]: (root) CMD (/home/a/Workspace/init.sh)
```

What I did so far:

```
sudo crontab -u root -e

@reboot /home/a/Workspace/init.sh
```

init.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo sh -x /home/a/Workspace/start_zookeeper.sh >> /home/a/log.out &
sleep 10
sudo sh -x /home/a/Workspace/start_kafka.sh >> /home/a/log.out  &
sleep 10
sudo sh -x /home/a/Workspace/x-bot/start.sh >> /home/a/log.out &
sleep 10
sudo sh -x /home/a/Workspace/y-bot/start.sh >> /home/a/log.out &
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is facing a similar issue, I have solved it by using absolute paths and #!bin/sh in all the shell scripts.